# room/node navigation and managing connections

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, nodes

I have a question about data structure and class design (sorry for the length). To make it simple assume this is a game and I want to navigate between rooms (picture a series of 2D non-scrolling screens, e.g. early metroid/castlevania). Each room can have many exits (e.g. up, down, left, right edges and also there may be doors inside the room that take you to other places, e.g. like mario pipes). The exits may not be bi-directional and may change. I guess you'd call this a directed acyclic graph with cycles (whatever that is!).

Anyway, all I really need to know from this are for a specific room (i.e. the current one - no need to traverse the whole map), what rooms can be navigated to (I may wish to show this list to the user or assume I can get the specific exit at some point). I'd like the best design approach avoiding all the basic pitfalls like tight coupling, following SRP, etc.

My first thought was something simple (code simplified):

```
class RoomConnection {
    Room toRoom;
    int exitItem;  //assume we can easily get/create this and represents the door/edge/etc
}

class Room {
    int id;
    List<RoomConnection> exits;
}

class Rooms {
    List<Room> rooms;
    Room getRoom(int id) {};
}
```

While this would suffice and my driver is not to over complicate I don't like this for a few reasons:
1. It seems to be tightly coupling connections with rooms
2. I'd like to store these things in one or more flat files (e.g. text file or database tables) so want to avoid nested structures

So my next idea was to separate them:

```
class RoomConnection {
    Room fromRoom;
    Room toRoom;
    int exitItem; 
}

class RoomConnections {
    List<RoomConnection> connections;
    Room getExitsForRoom(Room room) {};
}

class Room {
    //no reference to connections;
}

class Rooms {
    List<Room> rooms;
    Room getRoom(int id) {};
}
```

But I figured that's just adding list managers for the sake of it and is it any better design as it still links room and roomconnection quite closely and how does a Room know what it's exits are?

So my final thought is create some kind of facade, either:
1. As the previous example but remove the getExitsForRoom and put it in the facade, e.g.

```
class MapFacade {
    RoomConnections connections;
    Rooms rooms;

    List<Room> getExitsForRoom(Room r) {}
    //this or provide methods for managing rooms/connections here too
    MapFacade(RoomConnections c, Rooms r) {}

}
```

1. Dispense with the Rooms and RoomConnections completely and have the facade store a List and List with methods to maintain the lists and provide utility methods like getExitsForRoom, etc.

   class MapFacade {
       List connections=new ArrayList;
       List rooms=new ArrayList;

   ```
   List<Room> getExitsForRoom(Room r) {}
   void addRoom(Room r);
   void addConnection(Room fromRoom, Room toRoom, int exitID) {}
   ```

   }

Anyone got any thoughts? btw, I looked at various graphs which I guess I could use instead of the 'facade' but it seemed like overkill and doesn't provide an obvious answer to how does a room get its exits or who manages everything.

Comment: "The exits may not be bi-directional and may change. I guess you'd call this a directed acyclic graph (DAG)" -> I guess you should/can lookup the definition in Wikipedia. Can there be cycles in your graph? If so it is not a DAG. Technically even A->A and A->B->A are cycles. So if you have at least one loop edge or one undirected edge (which is same as having two directed edges between the two nodes in both directions), you will have a cycle already. What you're trying to model is just a graph or a multi graph (provided there may be more than 1 connection between 2 rooms).

Comment: thanks, I've updated my post, but what I'm interested in really is not graph theory but rather something much simpler - the best class design approach to managing my rooms and knowing the exits. But yes it may/will be cyclic in that A->B, A->C, A->D, B->A C->E

Comment: Well, OK, but I think you cannot design such a thing in a decent way without knowing a bit graph theory (at least some basic concepts and representations).

Answer (score 2):

One possible class design is:
- define a class Room, give each instance of it a unique ID; you may add other properties here too - properties of the Room/Node
- define a class RoomConnection (having fields **start** and **end** /both are of type Room/, actually you may decide not to add these two properties here at all); give each instance of it a unique ID; you may add other properties here too - properties of the RoomConnection/Arc
- define class Graph which contains a map mapping each Room (Node) to a list of its outgoing RoomConnections (Arcs)
- now define all methods here in Graph that you need; the Graph will hold it all
- you can reuse your Graph as factory of Room and RoomConnection instances (just add the proper methods)

This is a pretty standard representation of a Graph I would say.
It supports multi-Graphs too (graphs in which you may have 
more than one arc A->B between two nodes - note the unique IDs).

Comment: so essentially it's my final 'facade' example but there is no need to store a list of rooms, just connections? would you consider passing the Graph object around as some kind of context a bad apprach, e.g. to the Room constructor to allow a Room to find it's own exits?

Comment: @Neil This Graph is your whole model. I don't think a Room (which is a part of it) would be wise to know about the Graph. But if you really want that, make Graph a Singleton or globally accessible in some other way. But again, I find this a bad idea. Your logic or controllers or processors should work on the model/Graph, why does Room need to know about it? It's like having an element of an ArrayList point to the ArrayList it is stored in.

Comment: I guess I haven't fully decided how I'm going to control the whole system yet I'm just working from the bottom up without a full plan and my head is still just thinking about rooms :) but yes I guess room probably doesn't need to know about the graph.

Comment: @Neil I see. Apparently that's going to be a middle-sized or big system. Looks interesting btw. I guess I was no much help. Good luck anyways.

Comment: No, it is. Your answer tells me not to bother with Rooms and Connections as separate classes and to let the graph effectively store all the rooms and locations (I assume this is what you mean) and manage them. btw, this is actually for an Adventure game ("you are in the gloomy wood, you can see a troll. Your exits are north, south, east, west") :)

Comment: @Neil As a side note: I would suggest you look into the observer pattern. I think it is one possible way of designing such/similar systems. Every object registers itself to listen to only those event types it is interested in. Also every object can fire events. It is a nice way of decoupling objects (not having them keep references to each other) while still having them maintain complex communication.

Comment: cheers. btw, i like your idea of maps too for the exits, I'm using google guava already for PreConditions and their multimap is perfect for this. My Room is already immutable (in so far as equals/hash goes) so using that as a key is ideal too.